# mysql returned empty result set even records are existing

Tags: select, count, phpmyadmin

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT( bilno ) 
FROM trans_master
WHERE dt
BETWEEN 25-10-2017
AND 03-11-2017
AND refid=1
```

Below is table (trans_master):

[image]

Comment: Can you show your table data?

Comment: i posted an image file of my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add ' in front of and behind your date:

```
SELECT COUNT( bilno ) 
 FROM trans_master
WHERE dt
BETWEEN '25-10-2017'
AND '03-11-2017'
AND refid=1
```

Comment: Please test again with  >= and <=

Comment: its working now even it has worked only with quotations i don't know what i did wrong when i tried using of quotations before it was not worked but now its working any way thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: I am glad that it is working for you, I edited the answer to the 1st version. You can mark it as your answer and wish you have a nice day :)